# Obter nome em Select Join

Tags: codeigniter

Vejam a seguinte função:

```
$id_contratos = array_map(function($item)
{ return $item['id'];}, $result['contratos']);

$empresa = " -- aqui eu preciso recuperar o nome da empresa --";
$view["empresa"] = $empresa;
```

E a tabela com os seguintes campos:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_devedor_contrato`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_devedor_contrato` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`plano` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`contrato` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
`dt_contrato` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`dt_expiracao` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`devedor_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`empresa_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`importacao_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`crud` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Sabendo que o `id` da tabela `tbl_devedor_contrato` é igual a `$id_contratos`, eu quero recuperar a informação do campo `empresa_id` desta mesma tabela e tendo a informação deste campo, eu preciso utiliza-lo para fazer um join e obter o `nome_fantasia` da empresa, referente ao `int` obtido em `empresa_id`.

Sei que precisaria fazer primeiro um `select` e depois um join, mas já tentei e não deu certo.

Abaixo a tabela, para obter o `nome_fantasia`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_empresa`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_empresa` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cnpj` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`nome_fantasia` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`razao_social` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cep` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`logradouro` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
`numero` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`complemento` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`bairro` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`cidade` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`uf` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`telefone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_assessoria` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`dt_cadastro` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`dt_atualizacao` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`situacao` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Variável de `$result['contratos']`:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
     (
        [id] => 1
        [plano] => 4
        [contrato] => 93642059600
        [dt_contrato] => 2017-11-01
        [dt_expiracao] => 2017-11-30
        [devedor_id] => 1
        [empresa_id] => 1
        [importacao_id] => 0
        [crud] => R
    )
)
```

Comment: Posta o seu SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Para que você consiga fazer isto no codeigniter, basta usar o JOIN na sua função de retorno dos dados, da seguinte maneira:

```
public function get_devedor_contrato(){
    $this->db->select("tbl_devedor_contrato.*, tbl_empresa.razao_social");
    $this->db->join("tbl_empresa", "tbl_empresa.id=tbl_devedor_contrato.empresa_id");
    return $this->db->get('tbl_devedor_contrato')->result();
}
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso utilizar o `id` como parâmetro.

Comment: @WagnerFilho explica melhor